# How to upload notebook contents to jupyter server using jupyter server rest api calls using java?

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter server with python language support. I have created my jupyter notebook with print statement in it and downloaded that notebook to my local machine.
Now i have to read the contents of the locally stored notebook and upload to running jupyter server using jupyter server rest api calls.
I prefer java programming language to interact with jupyter server rest api calls to upload the notebook contents.

Problem : I am able to read the contents and call the jupyter server api by preparing the request body which is expected in the request.
I am calling this api of jupyter server : PUT :{base_url}/api/contents/a.ipynb

request body :

```
                log.info("jsonNode string : "+jsonNode);
                JSONObject modelRequest = new JSONObject();
                modelRequest.put("name", "a.ipynb");
                modelRequest.put("path", "");
                modelRequest.put("type","notebook");
                modelRequest.put("format","json");
                modelRequest.put("mimetype","None");
                modelRequest.put("content",new JSONObject(jsonNode.toPrettyString()));
                modelRequest.put("writable","True");
                log.info("json model object : "+modelRequest);
```

I tried to upload the content key value with different format like String, JSONObject, json String and etc but i am not able to succeed with uploading the contents in jupyter server notebook.
I see the the notebook is getting created but that is with empty contents. Actually i am expecting the data which is passing in the content key should get uploaded i should see in the notebook in jupyter server.

Anyone has any idea or clue or implementation in java, how can i achieve this ?
I am following the jupyter server rest api documentation,
https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/rest-api.html
https://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyter/jupyter_server/master/jupyter_server/services/api/api.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/raw/v6.4.0/notebook/services/api/api.yaml with OpenAPI into the jupyter-client module of https://github.com/allen-ball/ganymede.  I created a trivial notebook with a single cell.

```
print(1 + 2);
```

`$$.nsc` is an instance of [NotebookServicesClient](https://allen-ball.github.io/ganymede/ganymede/jupyter/NotebookServicesClient.html) which is a subclass of the OpenAPI-genrated [ganymede.jupyter.notebook.ApiClient](https://allen-ball.github.io/ganymede/ganymede/jupyter/notebook/ApiClient.html).  With some experimentation, I was able to upload the content to the server (and subsequently open "copy.ipynb" in Jupyter Notebook) as follows.

```java
import ganymede.jupyter.notebook.*;
import ganymede.jupyter.notebook.api.*;
import ganymede.jupyter.notebook.model.*;
```

```java
var contents = new ContentsApi($$.nsc).apiContentsPathGet("trivial.ipynb", "file", "text", 1);

print(contents);
```

```
class Contents {
    name: trivial.ipynb
    path: trivial.ipynb
    type: file
    writable: true
    created: 2021-08-02T00:03:43.820449Z
    lastModified: 2021-08-02T00:03:43.820449Z
    size: 648
    mimetype: text/plain
    content: {
     "cells": [
      {
       "cell_type": "code",
       "execution_count": 1,
       "id": "f74b3993",
       "metadata": {},
       "outputs": [
        {
         "data": {
          "text/plain": [
           "3"
          ]
         },
         "execution_count": 1,
         "metadata": {},
         "output_type": "execute_result"
        }
       ],
       "source": [
        "print(1 + 2);"
       ]
      }
     ],
     "metadata": {
      "kernelspec": {
       "display_name": "Ganymede 2.0.0 (Java 11)",
       "language": "java",
       "name": "ganymede-2.0.0-java-11"
      },
      "language_info": {
       "file_extension": ".java",
       "mimetype": "text/x-java",
       "name": "java",
       "version": "11"
      }
     },
     "nbformat": 4,
     "nbformat_minor": 5
    }
    
    format: text
}
```

```java
var model = new InlineObject();

model.setName("copy.ipynb");
model.setType("file");
model.setFormat("text");
model.setContent(contents.getContent());

var newContents = new ContentsApi($$.nsc).apiContentsPathPut(model.getName(), model);

print(newContents);
```

```
class Contents {
    name: copy.ipynb
    path: copy.ipynb
    type: notebook
    writable: true
    created: 2021-08-02T01:01:07.904684Z
    lastModified: 2021-08-02T01:01:07.904684Z
    size: 648
    mimetype: null
    content: null
    format: null
}
```